# ASP.NET MVC ... navigation and show error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

In an ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) application, the main screen is divided in 2 parts 
(2 div named : leftColumn and rightcolum, the leftcolumn is the menu, the rifhtcolumn is the content)

I. I click on an item in the menu, the "Add" screen appear in the rightcolumn

**HTML**

```
var jqxhr = $.post("/Customer/Add", function (data) {
    $('#rightcolumn').html(data);
})
.success(function() {})
.error(function() { })
.complete(function () { });
```

**Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult Add()
{
    return PartialView("Add");
}
```

II. I fill the form and I post, if the insert is success I display the customer list, if there is an error I'd like keep the form with the value already filled in 
(and this last point make problem for me) and show the error message in a jquery UI model form.
HTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Save(CustomerModel model)
{
    SaveOrUpdate(model);

    if(model.hasError())
        return ReturnToAction("Add", model);
    model.List = GetList();
    return View("List", model);
}
```

I have two problem :

1. When there is an error, the "Add" view is displayed but not in the right column but in full window without layout
2. The model (the client data) are not in the model.

How can I do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: When there's *any* kind of error, or some error in particular?

Comment: Have you checked the html source of the page? Are there still two divs for the right and left column?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAXify this form so that it updates only the `rightColumn` div when it is submitted. The [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) is very good for this purpose:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Add", "Customer")', function (data) {
    $('#rightcolumn').html(data);
    ajaxifyForm();
});
```

where the `ajaxifyForm` function might look like this:

```
function ajaxifyForm() {
    $('#rightcolumn form').ajaxForm(function(data) {
        $('#rightcolumn').html(data);
        ajaxifyForm();
    });
}
```

Comment: the problem is not submit the form. But keep the form and display the error message in a div when error on server side

Comment: @Kris-I, by AJAXifying the form, when you submit it the entire page will not reload but only the form and if there is an error it will show the error message in the `rightcolumn` div.

Comment: 1. when I do like this the controller does not receive the model filled in. 2. In your sample code how know error on server side ?